# Can I charge my Lumia Windows 8 with an LG charger

Tags: battery, charging

My original Lumia Windows 8 phone charger that came with the device was stolen and now I am subjected to use an alternate phone charger (LG) until I can purchase a new Lumia charger. I can't remember the exact model Lumia, but I purchased it in July 2015, less than a year old.

Can someone please shed some light on this for me. The LG charger specs that I have access to are 100-240v 60hz 0.2amp.

Answer (score 2):

The ratings that you've given seems to be of input, check the output rating of your LG charger. I've Lumia 730 & it's official charger has 5v DC, 750mA output rating. These rating may also be applicable to your Lumia Handset.

However, you can find the exact model of your Lumia from settings in '**extras + info**' or in '**about**' option.

Check the real rating of charger of your lumia headset from Internet & match it with LG charger. If ratings & other specifications are near to each other then you can use the LG charger. The charging may be slow or fast depending upon the current rating of your LG charger.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I followed your suggestions and my phone charged perfectly. This will suffice until I upgrade to a better Lumia next week. Thanks again for your help and advice

Comment: Nathan, I went out and bought a new charger after temporarily borrowing a friends LG charger. It's a dual USB Home adapter, The output is 5v DC and 2.1A. It works pretty good for my Lumia 635. I'm still going to upgrade on a new Lumia next week, but what I have for now will suffice. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: You're Welcome. When it comes to chargers, always go for official chargers as they are good for the battery health or battery life of phone or a device. If your Lumia doesn't indicates that 'This is not the official charger, your device will charge slowly', while charging with this Dual USB Charger then it must be OK. But I personally suggest to always go for official chargers; Charge your new Lumia with it's official charger (That will come with new Lumia), use this Dual USB charger as Backup or in emergency conditions.